# Traversal in a dynamically cloning created table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, cloning

I have created a page where I perform a search and the number of products are returned in the form of a row with its name, price and everything. The rows are created dynamically using the `clone` feature of jQuery. There is a checkbox in each row which is also created via cloning.

What I am trying now is to traverse through each row and get the values in each row based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. But the traversal seems to be a problem here in a dynamically cloned table.

Comment: Please post your code, along with a clearer description of why it does not work for you.

Comment: What code do you have so far that's not working? Make sure you explain *how* it's not working and what it *should* be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope that i have understood your challenge correctly. this example shows an alert with the checkbox value of cloned rows that contain a checked checkbox, ignoring those which are unchecked. while i am certain this is not exactly what you are looking for, you can use this as an example as to how to traverse the cloned table.

[here is the example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/seanmcmills/UvUGm/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

      var orig_table_rows = $('#original_table').children().clone();

      $("#new_table").append(orig_table_rows);

      orig_table_rows.children().each(function() {
        $(this).find("input:checked").each(function() {
          alert( $(this).val() );
        });
      });

    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

original table:
<table id="original_table" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="not_checked_value"></td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="checked_value" checked></td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="another_checked_value" checked></td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" value="not_checked_value"></td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>price</td>
    <td>everything</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<br>

table using the cloned rows:
<table id="new_table" style="border:1px solid blue;">
</table>

</body>
</html>
```